# Apache and Command Prompt running two different version of PHP on windows

Tags: php, apache, command-prompt

Yesterday, I installed Pear. During installation it asked me installation path of php. But, i mistakely entered different path. So, Pear installed different php version in that Path.

**Problem**
Now, my apache runs php `v5.5` as always. But, from yesterday, command prompt runs `v5.3`!

How can I make changes so that command prompt runs same version as apache `i.e. v5.5`.??

I am using windows.

Comment: Edit your path variable, replacing the path to v5.3 with the path to v5.5.

Comment: Where do i change the path variable?

Comment: This guide looks pretty good: http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/

Comment: Thanks @jameslafferty.It worked perfectly!

Comment: Converted this to an actual answer, just so it's more useful for others with the same issue. Could you mark my answer as the answer?

Comment: Ofcourse! And did it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your path variable, replacing the path to v5.3 with the path to v5.5. [This guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/) provides some good info on how to edit the system path.